# Need wordpress permalink solution

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type named as "vendors" and its taxonomies as "vendors_category",

I need to have permalinks like

> ../vendors/{business-name}
>
> ../vendors/categories/{category-name}

find out code below for post type ,

```
        register_post_type('vendors', array(
            'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __("Vendor Listings", ACL_PLUGIN_TD),
                    'singular_name' => __("Vendor Listing", ACL_PLUGIN_TD)
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'vendors',
                'with_front' => false
                ),              
            'query_var' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_icon' => ACL_PLUGIN_CUSTOM_URL . '/images/listings.png',
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        ) );    

        flush_rewrite_rules();
```

And for taxonomies

```
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => __( 'Vendor Categories' ),
            'singular_name'     => __( 'Vendor Category' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Vendor Categories' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Vendor Categories' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Vendor Category' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Vendor Category:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Vendor Category' ), 
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Vendor Category' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Vendor Category' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Vendor Category' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Vendor Categories' ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'vendors/categories',
                'with_front' => false
                ),              
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'vendors_category', 'vendors', $args );          
        flush_rewrite_rules();
```

But when i created taxonomy-vendors_category.php , it does not works with this code and always shows me page not found error.. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: is it working when you try to access page with default categories?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9bap8v , see the snap here in admin it generated the links properly . but when i click on view it did not worked...

default post and post categories permalinks works good.

Comment: Does your permalink structure is default?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9bauki - Please check here